# MemoryError при использовании sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, матрицы, scikit-learn

Я пробую обучать свою модель

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
alphas = [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.5, 1, 3,  5]
clf = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, normalize=True, gcv_mode = 'eigen').fit(x_train, y_train)
```

При этом:

```
print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
(62313, 100600) (62313,)

type(x_train)
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

До запуска у меня свободно примерно 10 гигабайт оперативной памяти. После старта занимается примерно 2 гигабайта и остается свободно еще 8. Мой код работает около полу часа, при этом свободная память находится в районе 8 гигов все время, а потом падает с ошибкой:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e9d3d7210319> in <module>()
      2 from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeCV
      3 alphas = [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.01, 0.5, 1, 3,  5]
----> 4 clf = RidgeCV(alphas=alphas, normalize=True, gcv_mode = 'eigen').fit(x_train, y_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1112                                   gcv_mode=self.gcv_mode,
   1113                                   store_cv_values=self.store_cv_values)
-> 1114             estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
   1115             self.alpha_ = estimator.alpha_
   1116             if self.store_cv_values:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1027         centered_kernel = not sparse.issparse(X) and self.fit_intercept
   1028 
-> 1029         v, Q, QT_y = _pre_compute(X, y, centered_kernel)
   1030         n_y = 1 if len(y.shape) == 1 else y.shape[1]
   1031         cv_values = np.zeros((n_samples * n_y, len(self.alphas)))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py in _pre_compute(self, X, y, centered_kernel)
    883     def _pre_compute(self, X, y, centered_kernel=True):
    884         # even if X is very sparse, K is usually very dense
--> 885         K = safe_sparse_dot(X, X.T, dense_output=True)
    886         # the following emulates an additional constant regressor
    887         # corresponding to fit_intercept=True

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    133     """
    134     if issparse(a) or issparse(b):
--> 135         ret = a * b
    136         if dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray"):
    137             ret = ret.toarray()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    477             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    478                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 479             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    480 
    481         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    500                                     maxval=nnz)
    501         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 502         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    503         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    504 

MemoryError:
```

Помогите разобраться, что происходит и можно ли с этим что-то сделать?

Comment: какой у вас объем RAM? и какой у вас тип данных?

Comment: RAM = 16, тип данных: `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`

Comment: Сколько у вас ненулевых элементов?

Comment: Мало, но с ходу не берусь сказать, сколько их. Как это узнать?

Comment: len(x_train.data) = 66112691. Но не уверен, что это то, что надо

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.count_nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.count_nonzero

Comment: Ага, все то же 66112691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на комментарий из `error traceback`:

```
# even if X is very sparse, K is usually very dense
```

из этого блока:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py in _pre_compute(self, X, y, centered_kernel)
    883     def _pre_compute(self, X, y, centered_kernel=True):
    884         # even if X is very sparse, K is usually very dense
--> 885         K = safe_sparse_dot(X, X.T, dense_output=True)
```

В вашем случае вы работаете с разреженной матрицей размерности `(62313, 100600)` у которой `66112691` ненулевых элементов (приблизительно 1% от общего числа элементов). Для хранения такой матрицы понадобится приблизительно 500MiB памяти:

```
In [21]: 66112691 * 8 / 1024**3
Out[21]: 0.4925779327750206
```

как следует из комментария выше, после выполнения:

```
K = safe_sparse_dot(X, X.T, dense_output=True)
```

`K` будет содержать очень большой процент ненулевых элементов. Для хранения матрицы `K` (если учесть что она не содержит нулевых элементов) понадобится дополнительно около 29GiB RAM:

```
In [23]: 62313**2 * 8 / 1024**3
Out[23]: 28.929933674633503
```

*NOTE:* во всех расчетах я исходил из того, что каждая ненулевая ячейка матрицы занимает 8 байт (для типов данных `int64` или `float64`). Если у вас другой тип данных - замените 8 на соответствующее число (число байт для хранения одного ненулевого элемента).

Я думаю вам стоит подумать об уменьшении размерности входной матрицы.

Comment: Теперь я понял, почему мой код падает. Но можно ли с этим можно сделать ? Я потому и передавал sparse матрицу, чтобы место экономить. Может есть идеи, как я могу использовать кросс валидацию для  ridge? Или возможно мне просто следует использовать другую модель?

Comment: Практически во всех моделях будет использоваться матричное умножение, которое будет из разреженной матрицы делать "обычную". Поэтому я не вижу выхода кроме уменьшения входной матрицы. Вполне возможно есть модели или способы позволяющие обойти эту проблему, но мне они неизвестны

Comment: Когда я просто использую ridge, у меня нет никаких проблем. Буду думать, как уменьшить матрицу. Спасибо!